# Auto validate Div inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, spring

My knowledge on JavaScript is very limited and I need to implement this front end validation please.

So I am using Spring back-end and need to do some front end validation on a form input I have. 
There will be 10 of these rows enclosed as Divs with the same input for each row.

eg. the inputs will be in this format

```
total[0]|qty[0]||qty[0]||qty[0]
total[1]|qty[1]||qty[1]||qty[1]
total[2]|qty[2]||qty[2]||qty[2]
```

etc...

```
total[10]|qty[10]||qty[10]||qty[10]
```

The user will first have the option to enter a total amount first.

The user has the option to enter inputs for qty of each row.

If the total of qty[0] are not equal to the total (total[0]) the user entered, the input box corresponding to that row will turn red(to inform the user they have inputted the wrong total).

```
  eg qty[0] + qty[0] qty[0] != total[0] (BOX GOES RED FOR total[0])
     qty[1] + qty[1] qty[1] = total[1] (NO CHANGE TO TOTAL BOX FOR total[1])
```

No other validation is needed apart from a visual one after the user keys in the last input for qty on that individual row.

Upon Clicking enter on the last input(qty[0] or qty[1] if the user is on the second row, or qty[10] if the user is on the last row) the validation will kick in and check is the box with id ="total[${status.index}]" = the three inputs with id = "qty[${status.index}]"

```
<!-- total -->
       <div class="span1_5">
       <form:input path="items[${status.index}].total" size="4"
        id = "total[${status.index}]" />
      </div>

  <!--qtyDis-->
   <div class="span1_5">
   <form:input path="items[${status.index}].qtyDis"size="4"
      onblur="findTotal()" 
     id ="qty[${status.index}]" />
  </div>

 <!--qtyAva-->
 <div class="span1_5">
   <form:input path="items[${status.index}].qtyAva"size="4"
      onblur="findTotal()" 
     id ="qty[${status.index}]" />
  </div>

   <!--qtyDat-->
  <div class="span1_5">
   <form:input path="items[${status.index}].qtyDat"size="4"
      onblur="findTotal()" 
     id ="qty[${status.index}]" />
  </div>
```

I am very weak at Javascript and this is all I was able to come up with. I know it will be far of, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var index = 0;
function findTotal(){
    var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty')[index];
    var tot=0;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
            tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
    }

    document.getElementById('total')[index].value = tot; 
    <!-- if not equal, change the css backround of total[index] to red -->
    index++;
}

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/oyw4owzo/#&togetherjs=mla1BbGOzm):

**JS:**

```
function findTotal($this) {
            var cls = $($this).attr("class");
            var index = cls.split('qty')[1];
            var totalsum = 0;
            $('.' + cls).each(function () {
                if ($.isNumeric($(this).val())) {
                    totalsum += parseInt($(this).val());
                }
            });
            if ($.isNumeric($(".total" + index).val())) {

                if (totalsum != parseInt($(".total" + index).val())) {
                    $(".total" + index).addClass('error');
                }
                else {
                    $(".total" + index).removeClass('error');
                }
            }

        }
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div>
            <div class="span1_5"><span>total1:</span><input type="text" class="total1" /></div>
            <div class="span1_5"><span>qty1</span><input type="text" class="qty1" onblur="findTotal(this)" /></div>
            <div class="span1_5"><span>qty1</span><input type="text" class="qty1" onblur="findTotal(this)" /></div>
            <div class="span1_5"><span>qty1</span><input type="text" class="qty1" onblur="findTotal(this)" /></div>
        </div>
    <br /><br /><br />
        <div>
            <div class="span2_5"><span>total2:</span><input type="text" class="total2" /></div>
            <div class="span2_5"><span>qty2</span><input type="text" class="qty2" onblur="findTotal(this)" /></div>
            <div class="span2_5"><span>qty2</span><input type="text" class="qty2" onblur="findTotal(this)" /></div>
            <div class="span2_5"><span>qty2</span><input type="text" class="qty2" onblur="findTotal(this)" /></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

This is just to make you an idea of how could you do, don't copy/paste directly because maybe there is some typo. But the main steps are:

- Add classes to each Quantity input so you can select them by row
- Recover the total by row
- Make a loop for all Quantities by Row and compare with total

In your HTML add classes to identify each element of any row

```
 <div class="span1_5">
   <form:input path="items[${status.index}].total" size="4"
    class="total${status.index}"  
    id = "total[${status.index}]" />
  </div>

 <!--qtyDis-->
 <div class="span1_5">
 <form:input path="items[${status.index}].qtyDis"size="4"
    onblur="findTotal()" class="qty${status.index}"
   id ="qty[${status.index}]" />
 </div>

 <!--qtyAva-->
 <div class="span1_5">
   <form:input path="items[${status.index}].qtyAva"size="4"
     onblur="findTotal()" class="qty${status.index}"
    id ="qty[${status.index}]" />
 </div>

 <!--qtyDat-->
 <div class="span1_5">
   <form:input path="items[${status.index}].qtyDat"size="4"
    onblur="findTotal()" class="qty${status.index}"
    id ="qty[${status.index}]" />
 </div>
```

Then in your JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   var index = 0;
   function findTotal(){
        var quantity = document.getElementsByClassName('qty' + index);
        var totQty=0;
        for(var i=0;i<quantity.length;i++){
            if(parseInt(quantity[i].value))
            totQty += parseInt(quantity[i].value);
        }

     <!-- if not equal, change the css backround of total[index] to red -->
     if(document.getElementById('total' + index).value != totQty){
          $('.qty'+index).addClass("error");
     }
    index++;
 }

</script>
```

Comment: Hi @Cralfaro, I tried you solution but when ever I click enter to go to the next input, The index is incremented by 1 every time the function is accessed. So when you get to the last value for qtyDat QTY[0] the index is already equal to 3.  Any thoughts on how to overcome this?

Comment: @James_Ryan101 now we dont need to iterated with an index, we just should get all elements selected with a specific class and process them. And add this function findTotal(), should rename to checkTotal() in the on blur of any input